# Apollo client saving user data

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, apollo, apollo-client, redux-toolkit

I am new to apollo-client, I used to work with redux-toolkit to store user info (uesrname,email, etc..) && localStorage and then I could use that specific user info in every component.

I have no idea how to do it with the apollo-client.

```
  const [addUser, { loading }] = useMutation(USER_LOGIN, {
    update(_, { data: { loginUser } }) {
      console.log(loginUser);
    },
    variables: {
      username: values.username,
      password: values.password,
    },
    onError(error) {
      setError(error.message);
    },
  });
```

so here as you can see I fetched that data, now I want it to be saved through redux stroe and local storage to get this data from anywhere.
I just don't know what is the correct way of doing this. Would be glad to get some hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few methods to do what you described. You can see them outlined in the apollo docs [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#updating-local-data).

The easiest way to update your local data is to refetch the query. What will happen is after you execute a mutation, you can include a `refetchQueries` array in that mutation's options. This specifies which queries you want to refetch after the mutation occurs.

So to update your local state when you execute a mutation, it'd probably look like this:

```
  const [addUser, { loading }] = useMutation(USER_LOGIN, {
    refetchQueries: [
      {query: GET_POST}, // An object referencing query (a DocumentNode object parsed with the gql function) and variables
      'GetComments' // Query name (The name of a query you've previously executed)
     ],
    variables: {
      username: values.username,
      password: values.password,
    },
    onError(error) {
      setError(error.message);
    },
  });
```

However there are other methods in the docs, one of them  is by updating the cache directly, you can find an example in the docs [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#the-update-function).

Comment: Hi and thank you for the reply.
My goal is to get that "loginUser' info and put it in localStorage and in redux-store so for example I will be able to get that user username to the navbar or another components.

Comment: I see. When refetching the query to get the user, you could add an ```onCompleted``` callback which returns the query result. From there you can set it to local storage or redux store. That ```onCompleted``` will be called everytime your mutation gets called as it has the ```refetchQueries``` option.

Comment: Thank you ! 
I did it like this:   onCompleted({ loginUser }) {
      dispatch(login(loginUser));
    }, ----- login coming from userSlice and it setting this loginUser value into redux + localstorage